# How to prevent or get rid off the "Ok Done" alert in chrome (and what is causing it)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm building on a project that (unfortunately) has javascript that gives some elements inline-styles.

For my part, I need to get rid off the inline styles when the web page hits a mobile a view, so I made a jquery solution:

```
$(".promo, .cc-minwrap, .premium-features, .feature-wrapper, .notice, .navi1").attr("style", "");
```

However, for some reason, on chrome when I ran this an "ok done!" message appeared. I figured it was because the jquery was taxing on the DOM, so I made a pure javascript solution which ran without inconveniences:

```
 var items = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("promo"), 0);
 items = items.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("premium-features"), 0));
 items = items.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("feature-wrapper"), 0));
 items = items.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("notice"), 0));
 items = items.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("navi1"), 0));

 for (var i = 0, max = items.length; i < max; i++) {
     items[i].style.cssText = "";
 }
```

To the point: How can I prevent the "ok done" message from showing and what exactly causes the message to show up. I don't want to use the pure javascript solution because it's hard to maintain and I still want to know why the jquery equivalent is doing what it does.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Looks like some external js/css. Does this come when you run your code on firefox?

Comment: Nope it didn't happen on firefox. Turned out to be the Diigo extension that was interfering (odd thing is that it only happens with the jquery version, nothing else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reproducing the error in an incognito window. It sounds like there's an extension interfering.

Comment: Oh, just realized adblock and diigo where still left on in incognito mode for some reason. Disable those to see if either of them where the culprits and turns out Diigo was causing it.